# I'm looking for a script that will rename files and place them in a new folder

Tags: windows

Essentially what I am looking to create is a script that will rename files in a folder, create a new folder with a specific name and place the renamed file in that new folder.

So, for instance, let's say that I had 2 files called:
test-spa.txt
test-ger.txt

I would then want to create 2 folders called spa and ger, respectively, place the appropriate file into each folder then rename the file by removing the language component; the resulting files in each folder would be test.txt.

Thanks,
Jaime

Comment: What have you tried so far? you need to post your code.

Comment: I actually don't have much experience with scripts, which is why I didn't try anything. Perhaps a better starter question would have been, given the above scenario, what type of script should I be looking to create? Such as a batch file, VBScript, command line, etc.

Comment: Well, actually StackOverflow is for solving programming problems, you can do this task in nearly whatever language you want and you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the simple solution I came up with to create folders and place specific files in them. So long as I have the bat file in the same folder it works great:

```
    @echo off

    md spa ger 

    move file.txt EN\file.txt 
    move file-spa.txt spa\file.txt
    move file-ger.txt ger\file.txt
```

I'm wondering if there is something missing that may cause an issue, such as specifying that this should only work in the current directory?